# JavaScript get child elements by className

Tags: javascript

I have written the following line in Javascript:

```
var eleCategory = document.getElementById("cmbCategory");
```

Now I want to find all `elementbyClassName` contained in the `eleCategory` element.

Is it possible with something like this?

```
 var eleChild = eleCategory.getElementByClassName("autoDropdown");
```

How can I get the child element of the parent element?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Issue Related to document.getElementByClassName() in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309071/issue-related-to-document-getelementbyclassname-in-javascript)

Comment: no it is different one. first was the hierarchy  className->ClassName this time i have hiearchy id->className

Comment: I see no reason why you couldn't use any of the answers in the previous question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` hasn't been implemented in all browsers. [Niels' solution](http://jsfiddle.net/ajAY2/), for instance, doesn't work in IE. However, others have created their own implementation; John Resig has a write-up on [his blog](http://ejohn.org/blog/getelementsbyclassname-speed-comparison/)

Answer (score 8):

Yes it is possible, see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ajAY2/

But the `getElementsByClassName` will return a collection of elements, because it will look for all classes within the object. So if you only got 1 class like that within this object, you have to get the 0th object like:

```
var eleChild = eleCategory.getElementsByClassName("autoDropdown")[0];
```

Total script:

Script:

```
var eleCategory = document.getElementById("cmbCategory");
var eleChild = eleCategory.getElementsByClassName("autoDropdown");
alert(eleChild.length);
```

HTML

```
<div id="cmbCategory">

    <div class="autoDropdown"></div>
    <div class="autoDropdown"></div>
</div>

<div class="autoDropdown"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var eleChild = eleCategory.childNodes;
for( i = 0 , j = eleChild.length; i < j ; i++ ){
    if( eleChild[ i ].className == "autodropdown" ){
        YOUr_SCRIPT
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access everything in DOM tree, with this:

```
document.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[0] ... n[n] ...
```

Just look for childnodes of childnodes.
And if I remember right, you can:

```
var element = document.getElementById("myid");
var child = element.childNode[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

For elegance, use the `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` methods.

```
var element = document.querySelector('#Element');
var elementChildren = element.querySelectorAll('.Element-child');
```

`elementChildren` will contain an array of all children with a class of `Element-child` within `element`.

Using bracket notation we could access the nth child in our array, e.g.

```
var firstElementChild = elementChildren[0]; // zero-based
```