# How to get all the descendants of an elements?

Tags: jquery

I know I can use parents to get all the ancestors. but it looks like children only return all the direct child. How to get all the descendants of an elements?

Comment: Where is your code and what are you tried so far?

Comment: i think it should help.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8337900/getting-child-elements-of-an-element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `.find("*")` syntax to find everything.

e.g.

```
$(element).find('*');
```