# Get the values of all text boxes having same parent div and show sum

Tags: javascript

I have two div of same class name and each div contains 5 input fields, 4 of them input fields and fifth one is for showing the sum.
Can someone help me in writing a JavaScript which triggers the onblur(), but get the amounts from the input fields of that div only and show the sum in its Total.
The Problem is all the input fields have same class name and even both div have same names so how will i differentiate between them.
I cant give them ids because i am generating it from a generic loop, the loop gets the data from the database and executes itself for the number of results from database.

```
<div class="feerow">
    <div class="feetext">
        <input class="amount"  type="text" data-feetype="8" data-clsec="345" />
    </div>
    <div class="feetext">
        <input class="amount"  type="text" data-feetype="9" data-clsec="345" />
    </div>
    <div class="feetext">
        <input class="amount"  type="text" data-feetype="10" data-clsec="345" />
    </div>
    <div class="feetext">
        <input class="amount"  type="text" data-feetype="11" data-clsec="345" />
    </div>
    <div class="feetext">
        <input class="amount" type="text" id="total" readonly="" disabled="disabled" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="feerow">
    <div class="feetext">
        <input class="amount"  type="text" data-feetype="8" data-clsec="346" />
    </div>
    <div class="feetext">
        <input class="amount"  type="text" data-feetype="9" data-clsec="346" />
    </div>
    <div class="feetext">
        <input class="amount"  type="text" data-feetype="10" data-clsec="346" />
    </div>
    <div class="feetext">
        <input class="amount"  type="text" data-feetype="11" data-clsec="346" />
    </div>
    <div class="feetext">
        <input class="amount" type="text" id="total" readonly="" disabled="disabled" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: And whats wrong with it ?@Craicerjack

Comment: My bad. Re-reading that link it seems I thought there was something in there thats not. Whats wrong with your question? Youre asking someone to solve a problem that you havent even tried to solve yourself. If you have tried to solve it, you should post that code or explain what you have done to try to solve it. Everyone here is happy to help, its a great resource, but its not a code writing resource. Try solve the problem yourself and if you run into specific issues then come back and ask for help with them.

Comment: I have tried and have been trying for the last 3 hours, Is it necessary to write so in the question that i have tried? I can post the codes but they aren't working. @Craicerjack

Comment: Its not necessary but it will show an effort on your part. As the question stands it looks like you havent done anything and just want someone else to write your code for you.

Comment: If you have tried something, post the code OR post what you tried and what specifically isnt working in what you tried. Youre much more likely to get help and get an answer.

Comment: Why not give the outer divs an id and this question might help with all the child elements - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8337900/javascript-get-child-elements-of-a-classname

Comment: I cant give them ids because i am generating it from  a generic loop, the loop gets the data from the database and executes itself for the number of results from database. @Craicerjack

Comment: Even if i give the id it would be the same for all of them. @Craicerjack

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75665/discussion-between-ali-malik-and-craicerjack).

Comment: You can get both outer divs with the `freerow` class with `getElementsByClassName('freerow');`. This will return a NodeList, which is essentially an array. Their indices will give you something unique to work with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example using plain javascript. I couldn't be bothered to test it in multiple browsers, but it seems to work fine in Chrome. Basically, whenever someone types something (you can use the `input` event instead of the `blur` event for more immediate results) it adds up all the numbers in the row and displays them in the total. I added a bit of code to format the result as dollars since it looked like you're dealing with money.

```js
function sumRow(row) {
  var fees = row.querySelectorAll("input:not(:disabled)"),
    total = Array.prototype.reduce.call(fees, function(sum, input) {
      return sum + (parseFloat(input.value) || 0);
    }, 0),
    formatted;

  if (total) {
    formatted = "$" + Math.round(100 * total);
    formatted = formatted.substr(0, formatted.length - 2) + "." + formatted.substr(-2);
  } else {
    formatted = "$0.00";
  }

  row.querySelector("input:disabled").value = formatted;
}

document.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
  sumRow(e.target.parentElement.parentElement);
});

window.addEventListener("load", function onLoad() {
  window.removeEventListener(onLoad);
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(".feerow"), sumRow);
});
```

```html
<div class="feerow">
  <div class="feetext">
    <input class="amount" type="text" data-feetype="8" data-clsec="345" />
  </div>
  <div class="feetext">
    <input class="amount" type="text" data-feetype="9" data-clsec="345" />
  </div>
  <div class="feetext">
    <input class="amount" type="text" data-feetype="10" data-clsec="345" />
  </div>
  <div class="feetext">
    <input class="amount" type="text" data-feetype="11" data-clsec="345" />
  </div>
  <div class="feetext">
    <input class="amount" type="text" id="total" readonly="" disabled="disabled" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="feerow">
  <div class="feetext">
    <input class="amount" type="text" data-feetype="8" data-clsec="346" />
  </div>
  <div class="feetext">
    <input class="amount" type="text" data-feetype="9" data-clsec="346" />
  </div>
  <div class="feetext">
    <input class="amount" type="text" data-feetype="10" data-clsec="346" />
  </div>
  <div class="feetext">
    <input class="amount" type="text" data-feetype="11" data-clsec="346" />
  </div>
  <div class="feetext">
    <input class="amount" type="text" id="total" readonly="" disabled="disabled" />
  </div>
</div>
```